# how to get the common elements from array and make new array sets?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
 let arrayA = ["Orange", "Apple", "grapes", "Orange", "Apple","Apple"]
```

Expected Result will be like this:

```
   let arrSet1 = ["Orange", "Orange"]
   let arrSet2 = ["Apple", "Apple", "Apple"]
   let arrSet3 = ["grapes"]
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself before asking your question?

Comment: Yes, I tried but not reached to best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution. you will get array with group of same values.

```
 var counts: [String: Int] = [:]
        for obj in arrayA {
            counts[obj] = (counts[obj] ?? 0) + 1
        }

        var array: [[String]] = []

        for i in counts.keys {
            var arr: [String] = []
            for j in 0..<counts[i]! {
                arr.append(i)
            }
            array.append(arr)
        }
        print(array)
```

Comment: While PGDev’s `Dictionary` based solution is probably easiest, if you were going to do it like outlined here, you could replace the above with a single, chained, functional expression: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/e3aaed062167a65b781d4f580be9d8b0

Comment: @Rob YOu are great thanks for your efforts. it is usefull like charm.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Dictionary's` **`init(grouping:by:)`**,

```
let arrays = Array(Dictionary(grouping: arrayA, by: {$0}).values)
print(arrays)
```

Now, from `arrays` create other arrSet1 and others like so,

```
let arrSet1 = arrays[0]
let arrSet2 = arrays[1]
let arrSet3 = arrays[2]
```

Make sure you access the `arrays` based on count otherwise it might throw *index out of bounds* exception.

Comment: @PGDev....PGDev Thanks for your help. this is exactly the easiest thing I like to do.